# Can headers still be requested even if there is no actual ".html" or ".php" file?

Tags: php, html, header, indexing, webserver

I'm currently working with an MCU that is established as a webserver. For starters, the MCU has the following pieces of code set:

```
#define HTTP_HEAD "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" \
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" \
    "Connection: Close\r\n" \
    "Content-Length: 1121\r\n\r\n" \
    "<!DOCTYPE html>" \
    "<html>" \
        "<head>" \
            "<style>" \
                    "#content{color: red; font-size: 50px;top: 70px;}" \
            "</style>" \
        "</head>" \
            "<body>" \
            "<center>" \
            "<div id='content'>" 

#define HTTP_TAIL "</center></body></html>\r\n\r\n"
```

This code is simply passed as string whenever there is a request for access in my webserver.

However, when I try and request the contents of this code through my other webserver in my PC I seem to get no data.

The PC side codes are shown below. It's just a basic example code from w3schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function()
        { 
            $("button").click(function()
            {    
                $.get("http://192.168.1.102/",function(data,status)
                {     
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);   
                });  
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Can a GET REQUEST still be sent to my webserver in my MCU even if it doesn't have a file named "index.php" or "index.html"??

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes - a GET request is passed on to the webserver, whose job it is to find what you want and then give it to you. Generally they can accept requests for files that don't exist, too - that's why you get 404 errors.

Have you tried running a Network inspect while that sample code is running? You'll probably see the GET request being issued and accepted by the webserver. In most browsers now that's all in F12.

Comment: Hi, for my first implementation I have set my MCU to be posting POST/GET request to my Webserver in pc, and then monitored it using the LiveHTTPheader extension in mozilla but it doesn't seem to detect any request. This lead me to make a "savingwithsocket.php" which basically is a php code that listens to any access to the port 80 of my PC side webserver and then writes it on a .txt file.
Upon POSTING/GETTING requests from my MCU I still didn't get any header.

this problem lead me to establish to establish the webserver in my MCU instead of my PC. And so those defines are in my MCU.

Comment: My current setup is that my MCU is the webserver, and on my PC I also have ANOTHER webserver running with the getrequest.php code with a `<script>` that basically just sends out a request to my MCU webserver. The problem is, the request is sent, but my MCU doesn't return anything. And so I tested it through direct access through a browser, which works fine. When I type in the URL(IP) of my MCU, it successfully returns the data that it's supposed to return. However, in my `<script>` code it doesn't.